# Postgres running a slower nested join loop instead of a hash join

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I've been optimizing some sql queries against a production database clone. Here is an example query where I've create two indexes where we can run index-only scans really fast using a hash join.

```
explain analyse
select activity.id from activity, notification
where notification.user_id = '9a51f675-e1e2-46e5-8bcd-6bc535c7e7cb'
and notification.received = false
and notification.invalid = false
and activity.id = notification.activity_id
and activity.space_id = 'e12b42ac-4e54-476f-a4f5-7d6bdb1e61e2'
order by activity.end_time desc
limit 21;

Limit  (cost=985.58..985.58 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=985.58..985.58 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
        Sort Key: activity.end_time DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=649.76..985.57 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (notification.activity_id = activity.id)
              ->  Index Only Scan using unreceived_notifications_index on notification  (cost=0.42..334.62 rows=127 width=16) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = '9a51f675-e1e2-46e5-8bcd-6bc535c7e7cb'::uuid)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Hash  (cost=634.00..634.00 rows=1227 width=24) (never executed)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using space_activity_index on activity  (cost=0.56..634.00 rows=1227 width=24) (never executed)
                          Index Cond: (space_id = 'e12b42ac-4e54-476f-a4f5-7d6bdb1e61e2'::uuid)
                          Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.299 ms
Execution time: 0.046 ms
```

And here are the indexes.

```
create index unreceived_notifications_index on notification using btree (
    user_id,
    activity_id, -- index-only scan
    id -- index-only scan
) where (
    invalid = false
    and received = false
);

space_activity_index
create index space_activity_index on activity using btree (
    space_id,
    end_time desc,
    id -- index-only scan
);
```

However, I'm noticing that these indexes are making our development database a LOT slower. Here's the same query against a user in our development database and you'll notice its using a nested loop join this time and the order of the loops is really inefficient.

```
explain analyse
select notification.id from notification, activity
where notification.user_id = '7c74a801-7cb5-4914-bbbe-2b18cd1ced76'
and notification.received = false
and notification.invalid = false
and activity.id = notification.activity_id
and activity.space_id = '415fc269-e68f-4da0-b3e3-b1273b741a7f'
order by activity.end_time desc
limit 20;

Limit  (cost=0.69..272.04 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=277.255..277.255 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.69..71487.55 rows=5269 width=24) (actual time=277.253..277.253 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Index Only Scan using space_activity_index on activity  (cost=0.42..15600.36 rows=155594 width=24) (actual time=0.016..59.433 rows=155666 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (space_id = '415fc269-e68f-4da0-b3e3-b1273b741a7f'::uuid)
              Heap Fetches: 38361
        ->  Index Only Scan using unreceived_notifications_index on notification  (cost=0.27..0.35 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=155666)
              Index Cond: ((user_id = '7c74a801-7cb5-4914-bbbe-2b18cd1ced76'::uuid) AND (activity_id = activity.id))
              Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.351 ms
Execution time: 277.286 ms
```

One thing to note here is that there is are only 2 space_ids in our development database. I suspect this is causing Postgres to try to be clever, but it's actually making performance worse!

My question is:

1. Is there some way that I can force Postgres to run the hash join instead of the nested loop join?
2. Is there some way, in general, that I can make Postgres's query-planner more deterministic? Ideally, the query performance characteristics would be the exact same between these environments.

Thanks.

---

**Edit:** Note that when I leave out the space_id condition when querying my dev database, the result is faster.

```
explain analyse
select notification.id from notification, activity
where notification.user_id = '7c74a801-7cb5-4914-bbbe-2b18cd1ced76'
and notification.received = false
and notification.invalid = false
and activity.id = notification.activity_id
--and activity.space_id = '415fc269-e68f-4da0-b3e3-b1273b741a7f'
order by activity.end_time desc
limit 20;

Limit  (cost=17628.13..17630.43 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=2.730..2.730 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=17628.13..17996.01 rows=3199 width=24) (actual time=2.729..2.729 rows=0 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 1
        Workers Launched: 1
        ->  Sort  (cost=16628.12..16636.12 rows=3199 width=24) (actual time=0.126..0.126 rows=0 loops=2)
              Sort Key: activity.end_time DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=20.59..16441.88 rows=3199 width=24) (actual time=0.093..0.093 rows=0 loops=2)
                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on notification  (cost=20.17..2512.17 rows=3199 width=32) (actual time=0.092..0.092 rows=0 loops=2)
                          Recheck Cond: ((user_id = '7c74a801-7cb5-4914-bbbe-2b18cd1ced76'::uuid) AND (NOT invalid) AND (NOT received))
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on unreceived_notifications_index  (cost=0.00..18.82 rows=5439 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = '7c74a801-7cb5-4914-bbbe-2b18cd1ced76'::uuid)
                    ->  Index Scan using activity_pkey on activity  (cost=0.42..4.35 rows=1 width=24) (never executed)
                          Index Cond: (id = notification.activity_id)
Planning time: 0.344 ms
Execution time: 3.433 ms
```

---

**Edit:** After [reading about index hinting](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/hinting_at_postgresql/), I tried turning nested_loop off using `set enable_nestloop=false;` and the query is way faster!

```
Limit  (cost=20617.76..20620.09 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=2.872..2.872 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=20617.76..21130.20 rows=4392 width=24) (actual time=2.871..2.871 rows=0 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=19617.74..19623.23 rows=2196 width=24) (actual time=0.086..0.086 rows=0 loops=3)
              Sort Key: activity.end_time DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=2609.20..19495.85 rows=2196 width=24) (actual time=0.062..0.062 rows=0 loops=3)
                    Hash Cond: (activity.id = notification.activity_id)
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on activity  (cost=0.00..14514.57 rows=64831 width=24) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=3)
                          Filter: (space_id = '415fc269-e68f-4da0-b3e3-b1273b741a7f'::uuid)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=2541.19..2541.19 rows=5441 width=32) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=3)
                          Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 64kB
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on notification  (cost=20.18..2541.19 rows=5441 width=32) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=3)
                                Recheck Cond: ((user_id = '7c74a801-7cb5-4914-bbbe-2b18cd1ced76'::uuid) AND (NOT invalid) AND (NOT received))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on unreceived_notifications_index  (cost=0.00..18.82 rows=5441 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=3)
                                      Index Cond: (user_id = '7c74a801-7cb5-4914-bbbe-2b18cd1ced76'::uuid)
Planning time: 0.375 ms
Execution time: 3.630 ms
```

Comment: Those are not really equivalent, I mean the second one finds 155666 matching rows in activity, and does that many loops! I don't know how applicable this is to your situation, but often to speed up a JOIN where you only want a small amount of data, you can do something like `SELECT ... FROM x JOIN (SELECT fields FROM table WHERE ... LIMIT 20) y ON x.field = y.field` to give it a much smaller dataset to work with. Or I do subqueries instead of a join if there are a small amount and the fields are indexed, e.g. `SELECT field, (SELECT v FROM table_b y WHERE x.a = y.b) FROM table_a x WHERE ...`

Comment: The queries are the same, but the query plans are different. Check out my latest edit.

Comment: It seems like your estimates are not good enough. Raise `default_statistics_target`, `ANALYZE` the tables and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how specialized you want to get.  There are plan guides in postgresQL that you can use to force the queries to use specific indexes.  But query optimizers are strongly impacted by record counts in the choices they make.  Maybe you add the extra indexes in the non-dev environment and move on?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sql-server-to-aurora-postgresql-migration-playbook/chap-sql-server-aurora-pg.tuning.queryplanning.html